# Verify whether this equation diagram is correct

Tags: simple-functions

I need to create an equation diagram representing a function written in python and I need help to verify that what I have created really means what I think it does. I am trying to say that if the value of *d* is one or more then *W* is equal to the division, if *d* is less than one then *W* should be equal to 1.

Here is the equation:
$$W=\begin{cases}
\lceil\frac{d}{s}\rceil&d>0\\
1&d<1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What does s have to do with anything? Do you have more information? This does not look like a function. If d=0.5, what is W?

Comment: I didnt know what to tag the question as so that is my fault. I will add what s is, I actually just wanted to know if the way its written represents an if, else

Comment: This "function" has two values in (0,1), hence it's not a function

Comment: When I say function, the function is written in python, and I just wan to know whether the diagram is representative of an if else condition.

Comment: @Mathboi so I need to put the conditions on the right hand side for it to be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d$ is $\geq1$ then W is equal to $\lceil\frac{d}{s}\rceil$, if $d<1$ then $W=1$.
The function is
$$W=\begin{cases}
\lceil\frac{d}{s}\rceil&d\geq1\\
1&d<1
\end{cases}$$